# Send Email Verification using Firebase (Unity)

Tags: c#, email, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I placed this code right on my signup process.

```
newUser.SendEmailVerificationAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
     UpdateErrorMessage("SendEmailVerificationAsync Success");
});
```

But this code is not sending email verifications on my email.
Can someone point out what i am missing. It's been bugging me for hours.
Thank you.

Comment: You may be experiencing delays in email delivery. Are the emails eventually getting through?

Comment: It was just a delay. Thank you :)